# must be a nonstatic member function

Tags: c++, class, object, operator-overloading

Trying to compile some code and I keep getting an error that says 
" 'myString& operator=(const myString&)' must be a nonstatic member function"

This is my namelist.cpp

```
myString& operator=(const myString& string)
  {
          if(this = &string)
                  return *this;

          data = new char[strlen(string.data)+1];

          strcpy(data, string.data);
        length = string.length;

          return *this;
  }
```

This is some of my namelist.h

```
  9 class myString
 10 {
 11 private:
 12         char* data;
 13         int length;
 14
 15 public:
 16         myString();
 17         myString(char cString[]);
 18         myString(myString& cString);
 19         //desctructor
 20         myString operator=(const myString& string);
 21         myString operator+(const myString& string);
```

Comment: The declaration in header doesn't match. misses '&'

Comment: Careful with that variable named `string`. One typo and a `using namespace std` and error messages can go from easy to read to nightmarishly arcane.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration should be:

```
myString& operator=(const myString& string);
```

And the definition:

```
myString& myString::operator=(const myString& string)
```

Comment: The thing is I had it like you said and i get an error that says " error:prototype for 'myString& myString::operator=(const myString&)' does not match any in class 'myString'. It specifically points to the myString::

Comment: Got it nvm. Thank you!